# insert php array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been hunting for a solution to this but I am having no luck. I am trying to load the results from an array into a mysql table.

What I know
- I am successfully connecting to the table
- When I run the attached code it returns "Not added" for the number of items in my array.

```
foreach ( $lender as $value ) {

$firm = trim( $value[ 0 ] );
$variable = trim( $value[ 1 ] );
$six_moths = trim( $value[ 2 ] );
$one_year = trim( $value[ 3 ] );
$two_year = trim( $value[ 4 ] );
$three_year = trim( $value[ 5 ] );
$four_year = trim( $value[ 6 ] );
$five_year = trim( $value[ 7 ] );

$today = date( "Y-m-d" );


echo "<br>";

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO current_rates(financial_instution, variable, six_months, one_year, two_year, three_year, four_year, five_year, today) VALUES('$firm', '$variable', '$six_month' , '$one_year', '$two_year', '$three_year', '$four_year', '$five_year', '$today')";
$result = @mysql_query( $qry );

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if ( $result ) {
    echo( "Added Success" );
} else {
    echo( "Not Added" );

}
```

}

Comment: you need to check for the real errors with error reporting and handling on the query

Comment: Take off that `@`, whats the error you are hiding?

Comment: put your entire code ,we need to know what was $lender before

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Comment: sorry, I guess I posted prematurely. I should have done more research. The real error is Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /Library/WebServer/Documents/lessons101/test.php on line 89
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)Not Added. Now to figure out why the password issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try it like below..
Did you check the db? Do you have a connection and is there a table called current_rates?

```
 $result = mysql_query($qry, $conn);
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have the connection work and now I am getting an error because of how my table is set up. MYSQL error: Incorrect integer value.  The value that I am trying enter into the table is 2.900. Current data type is set to -  six_months int(11). Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Change the datatype to REAL or DOUBLE or enter 2900 (without ".")

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

```
$six_moths
```

should be :

```
 $six_month
```

you typed month incorrectly